# Contour plot with 2 equations and 3 variables

Tags: plotting

I have $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$. I want to exclude parameter $z$ and extract a line $x(y)$.

I tried contourplot3D but then I need to map intersection of two surfaces onto x-y plane.

Comment: Depending on your functions, this is easy or extremely hard. So it would reduce the possible answers if you specify the form of your functions. Here is an example with linear and quadratic functions: f = x + y + z; 
g = x^2 - 2 y + 3 z^2; Solve[Eliminate[{f == 0, g == 0}, z], y]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometimes it is not easy to eliminate z, so we can use some tricks.

```
Clear[f, g];
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + Sin[z] - 1;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x*y*Log[Abs[z]] - 0.1;
ContourPlot3D[g[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]], 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Cyan}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.01], 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> {True, True, False}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, None}]
Export["eliminate-z.png", %]
```

[image]

Comment: great, thank you! I thought there is some 2d environment to achieve this projection, but this one is also fine.

Comment: The inner arc in the first and third quadrants is spurious, apparently arising from the essential singularity in `g` at `z = 0`.  This can be seen from `c0 = Cases[cp[[1, 1]] // Normal, {_, _, z_} /; Abs[z] < 10^-10, Infinity]`, where `cp` is the name assigned to the plot.  Then g @@@ c0 shows that `g` is not at all well satisfied for points near `z = 0`.  Otherwise, great answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

With `f` and `g` as defined in the answer by cvgmt,

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + Sin[z] - 1;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x*y*Log[Abs[z]] - 1/10;
```

a general solution solution can be obtained by

```
Flatten[DeleteCases[Quiet@Table[Check[{x0, 
    FindRoot[{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z]} /. x -> x0, {{y, y0}, {z, z0}}][[1, 2]]}, 
    Nothing], {x0, -2, 2, .04}, {z0, -5, 5}, {y0, -2, 2, .5}], {}, Infinity], 1];
ListPlot[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Cyan, PointSize[Medium]], ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Note, however, that more points, outside the circle `x^2 + y^2 = 2`, can be obtained by using imaginary numbers (e.g., `2 I`) as initial guesses for `z0`.  They are clustered near the axes.  An analytical solution for this particular set of equations can be obtained from

```
Reduce[f[x, y, z] == 0, z]
(* C[1] ∈ Integers && (z == Pi - ArcSin[1 - x^2 - y^2] + 2 Pi C[1] || 
   z == ArcSin[1 - x^2 - y^2] + 2 Pi C[1]) *)
```

which is equivalent to `z -> ArcSin[1 - x^2 - y^2] + Pi n`, with `n` an integer.  Then

```
sgt = Table[0 == g[x, y, z] /. z -> ArcSin[1 - x^2 - y^2] + Pi n, {n, -10, 10}];
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@sgt, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Cyan, 
         FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}], 
     ContourPlot[{x == 0, y == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Black], 
         ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

which agrees with my first plot for real `z` but extends to larger `x` and `y` for complex `z`.  Note that as `n` becomes ever larger, additional hyperbola-like curves fill the space near the axes (shown in `Black`) in the first and third quadrants.

The plots here differ from those in the answer by cvgmt in two respects.  First, my plots show numerous hyperbolas.  The method used by cvgmt also would display hyperbolas, if `{z, -2, 2}` were replaced by larger limits, say `{z, -10, 10}`.  Second, my plots do not show an inner arc of approximate radius `1` in the first and third quadrants.  To explore the discrepancy, I considered the two functions on the line `x = y`.

```
f[w, w, z] == 0
(* -1 + 2 w^2 + Sin[z] == 0 *)
g[w, w, z] == 0
(* 1/10 + w^2 Log[Abs[z]] == 0 *)
```

Plot the intersections of these two expressions for `w^2`.

```
Plot[{(1 - Sin[z])/2, 1/(10  Log[Abs[z]])}, {z, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {z, w^2}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The largest value of `w^2` lies near `z = -1`.

```
FindRoot[(10  Log[Abs[z]]) (1 - Sin[z])/2 == 1, {z, -1 + 0 I}]
w -> Sqrt[(1 - Sin[z])/2] /. %
(* {z -> -1.11123} *)
(* w -> 0.973716 *)
```

which lies on the outer arc, as expected.  The next largest value of `w^2` lies near `z = 2`.

```
FindRoot[(10  Log[Abs[z]]) (1 - Sin[z])/2 == 1, {z, 2 + 0 I}]
w -> Sqrt[(1 - Sin[z])/2] /. %
(* {z -> 2.28198} *)
(* w -> 0.348146 *)
```

which lies on the outer hyperbola-like curve.  Thus, there does not appear to be an inner arc.

**Addendum: Extension of answer by cvgmt**

The innovative answer by cvgmt can be extended by

```
ContourPlot3D[g[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -8, 11}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]], 
    MeshStyle -> {Cyan, Thickness[.002]}, ContourStyle -> None, 
    ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    Axes -> {True, True, False}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, None}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

The principle modification is to increase the range of `z` to `{z, -8, 11}` to capture the first five hyperbola-like curves.  Interestingly, doing so also eliminates the spurious inner arcs in the first and third quadrants.  Other changes are replacing `Opacity[0.01]` by `None` to eliminate essentially invisible surfaces, replacing `Thick` by `Thickness[.002]`to better distinguish among some of the curves, and eliminating the redundant  `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`.

[image]

Comment: +1.Deep thought!