# 2 equations 3 unknowns. Implicit 2D Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a hopefully simple question which I could not find any solution to yet:
With two equations in three unkowns x,y,z I would like to plot their solution in x,y space. I cannot get rid of z explicitly and simply plot the resulting x,y equation as the functions are complicated.
How can I tell Mathematica to do this graph for me?

Comment: Please provide your code! You can solve your problem using `ContourPlot[Eliminate[eqn,z],{x,...},{y,...}]`

Comment: Thank you for the very fast reply. I would hate to copy paste the original equations as they are messy. Just assume y=lnz and x=(1/2)z (where I could simply eliminate of course). How does the command look like?

Comment: ContourPlot[Eliminate[{y == lnz, x == 1/2 z}, z] {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] did not work for me as the programme "expects more arguments".

Comment: Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233870/contour-plot-with-2-equations-and-3-variables/233873#233873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct syntax all works fine:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[ Eliminate[{y == Log[z], x == 1/2 z}, z]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0,5}]
```

[image]

Comment: As always... Thank you Ulrich!

Comment: Hope it helps solving your problem!